# Azure DNS Zone www CNANE pointing to Azure Static Web Application not working without www

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I have an Azure DNS Zone, which has the @ (NS and SOA) as per Azure default configuration.

Then a www CNAME records pointing to an Azure Static Web Application.

This CNAME record works perfect when browsing [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but it does not serve when browsing domain.com

I've read at Microsoft that, by default, all traffic to domain.com will be redirected to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but it is not working in my case.

I tried adding *.domain.com pointing to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and even to the Azure static app value (xxxxxxx.azurestaticapps.net) but still have no luck.

Should I define a specific record for domain.com to work properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create DNS resource records for `domain.com`. Delete `*.domain.com`.

- Name: @
- Type: A - Alias to IPv4 address
- Alias: Yes
- Alias Type: select Azure resource

[Set up an apex domain with Azure DNS in Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apex-domain-azure-dns)

Comment: Thanks John, that worked perfect, but its not working for me when enabling Front Door. Its asking me to install my own SSL for root domains. Is there a way to forward example.com to https://www.example.com? Thanks again!